# Рендеринг HTML Qt

Tags: html, c++, qt, opengl

Имеется DOM дерево, нужен рендер на OpenGl,в Qt.Так как, у HTML нет координат, а OpenGL рисует по координатам, не понимаю как это сделать, по смещениям атрибутов или как?